# c++ boost split string

Tags: c++, boost, split

I'm using the `boost::split` method to split a string as this:

I first make sure to include the correct header to have access to `boost::split`:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

then:

```
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_any_of("\t"));
```

and the line is like

```
"test   test2   test3"
```

This is how I consume the result string vector:

```
void printstrs(vector<string> strs)
{
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = strs.begin();it!=strs.end();++it)
    {
        cout << *it << "-------";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

But why in the result `strs` I only get `"test2"` and `"test3"`, shouldn't be `"test"`, `"test2"` and `"test3"`, there are `\t` (tab) in the string.

**Updated Apr 24th, 2011:** It seemed after I changed one line of code at `printstrs` I can see the first string. I changed

```
cout << *it << "-------";
```

to

```
cout << *it << endl;
```

And it seemed `"-------"` covered the first string somehow.

Comment: Show how you work with the vector. I'd guess the issue is there.

Comment: `boost::is_any_of("\t")` is less efficient then `[](char c) { return c=='\t';}`. You just want to check a single possibility. (No idea why there's no `boost:is('\t')` )

Comment: What does the code in @MSalters comment mean? How do I use that code to substitute `boost::is_any_of()`?

Comment: @PoscoGrubb: It's called a "lambda", and `boost::splits` understands them.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem is somewhere else in your code, because this works:

```cpp
string line("test\ttest2\ttest3");
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_any_of("\t"));

cout << "* size of the vector: " << strs.size() << endl;    
for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++)
    cout << strs[i] << endl;
```

and testing your approach, which uses a vector iterator also works:

```cpp
string line("test\ttest2\ttest3");
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs,line,boost::is_any_of("\t"));

cout << "* size of the vector: " << strs.size() << endl;
for (vector<string>::iterator it = strs.begin(); it != strs.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Again, your problem is somewhere else. Maybe what you think is a `\t` character on the string, isn't. I would fill the code with debugs, starting by monitoring the insertions on the vector to make sure everything is being inserted the way its supposed to be.

Output:

```
* size of the vector: 3
test
test2
test3
```

Comment: There's nothing else we can do for you if you won't share a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are facing. Remember: MINIMAL EXAMPLE, not your full app.

Comment: thanks. it seemed I changed cout<<*it<< "-------"  to cout<<*it<<endl; I can see the first string. Not sure why, It looks "-------" covered the first string

Comment: FYI, following Boost headers are used in this sample: `#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>` and 
`#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>`

Comment: This does not work. Try string = "hih1ihi" and substring = "hi. The result of the work is incorrect.

Answer (score 15):

My best guess at why you had problems with the ----- covering your first result is that you actually read the input line from a file.  That line probably had a \r on the end so you ended up with something like this:

`-----------test2-------test3`

What happened is the machine actually printed this:

`test-------test2-------test3\r-------`

That means, because of the carriage return at the end of test3, that the dashes after test3 were printed over the top of the first word (and a few of the existing dashes between test and test2 but you wouldn't notice that because they were already dashes).

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class Container>
void split1(const std::string& str, Container& cont)
{
   boost::algorithm::split_regex(cont, str, boost::regex("\t"));
}

std::vector<std::string> vec1;
std::string str = "hest1\twest2\tpiest3";
split1(str, vec1);
```

vec == ("hest1","west2","piest3")