# Reading text file - C++

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

If my text file had something like:

```
111 Bob
222 Jim
333 Joe
444 Mike
555 Gary
```

I want to read each line and split each line into an ID number and a name in order to plug them into a function. How do I split up each line that is read from a file into two variables?

Comment: This is too broad. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line) 
Answers of this question show how to read a text file line by line.
And you can find how to split a string via this question.
[c++ boost split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734304/c-boost-split-string)